# Comparing URL's using Protractor

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, protractor, comparison, anchor

I have a page with URL -

http://localhost:7070/application/service-architecture/572RJ78544/summary

When I click on a particular button, the URL changes to -

http://localhost:7070/developer/service-architecture/572RJ78544/summary

Is there any way to verify that these two URL's refer to the same page, using Protractor? Or by using regular expressions or something of that sort

Eg - Say, Service Architecture and summary is same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not Protractor specific, more JS ;-)

If you have retrieved the url (with for example [`getCurrentUrl()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.getCurrentUrl)) you can `test` / `match` / `indexOf` your current url against a given url.

I usually use the [`test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) with a regex, but it's up to you what you want to use.

**For example:**

If you want to wait for an url to change from `http://example.com/foo` to `http://example.com/foo/bar` then you can use the below code in protractor to wait (for max 10 seconds) to change the url, else fail with a rejected promise

```
const urlRegExp = new RegExp('http://example.com/foo');
return browser.driver.wait(() => {
        return browser.driver.getCurrentUrl()
            .then(url => urlRegExp.test(url));
    }, 10000);
```

Hope this helps